# Is my bonsai tree still alive even though its leaves are dry and brown?

Tags: trees, tree-care, bonsai

[image: My bonsai tree today]About four months ago I watered my bonsai tree but it didn't soak in any water. Its leaves just hung. I changed its soil and removed all the rotten roots but nothing changed. Eventually, its leaves just dried out and became brown. They never fell off, they're stil hanging on the bonsai like that. The stem is completely firm and seems normal (as it seemed before this happened).

Is my bonsai tree still alive, and if it is, what should I do with it to help it live normally again?

Comment: Looks dead to me, sorry.

Comment: @benn That's what I was afraid of... Do you have any clue what might have happened to it?

Comment: My guess is that it didn't have enough water, but if you say it had rotten roots the opposite might also be the case. So with too much water, the roots rot and the plant can't take up any water anymore, and thus dries up as well. This happens a lot with bonsai, don't worry about it! Just try again and try to find cheap starting material (so it doesn't hurt too much).

Comment: @benn I watered it whenever its leaves started hanging down more than usual (a sign of hypertonic soil and plasmolysis as a consequence). Could it be that plasmolysis occured so many times that the cell membrane became permanently detached from the cell wall?